# OpenCV 2.4.5: FLANN and hierarchicalClustering

Tags: opencv, hierarchical-clustering, flann

I have recently started porting an application to a new platform which runs OpenCV 2.4.5.

Part of my code which uses OpenCV's implementation of FLANN to do hierarchical clustering no longer compiles.

The code is as follows:

```
cv::Mat mergedFeatures = cvCreateMat(descriptorTotal, descriptorDims, CV_32F);

int counter = 0;
for (uint j = 0; j < ImageFeatures.size(); j++) {
    cv::Mat features = ImageFeatures[j];
    for (int k = 0; k < features.rows; k++) {
        cv::Mat roi = mergedFeatures.row(counter);
        features.row(k).copyTo(roi);
        counter++;
    }
}

cv::Mat centers = cvCreateMat(1000, descriptorDims, CV_32FC1);
cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams k_params = cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams();
cv::flann::AutotunedIndexParams atp = cv::flann::AutotunedIndexParams();
int numClusters = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<float, float>(mergedFeatures, centers, k_params);
```

The error that I am getting (in Eclipse) is that cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering has invalid arguments and that neither of the candidates for this function are met.

Can someone explain how I suddenly seem to be calling this method incorrectly?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_clustering.html#flann-hierarchicalclustering-distance)?

Comment: Of course I have read the documentation.  I have fixed the problem myself anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem myself.

Instead of accepting:

```
cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams k_params
```

the hierarchicalClustering function actually needs:

```
cvflann::KMeansIndexParams k_params
```

It is rather a confusing namespace convention with the FLANN library in OpenCV and I had just overlooked the namespace difference in what the compiler error was telling me.

It is all working now.  The KMeansIndexParams type is present in both namespaces and I guess that the hierarchicalClustering method has changed very slightly from OpenCV 2.3 to 2.4.5.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the flann hierarchical clustering, in order to create clusters from multiple detected objects in a flann based match. I'm a newbie in OpenCV and even reading the documentation, I'm still not able to do the clustering. Now, I'm trying create an all zero Mat with white points for all the coordinates (x,y) of each match, and them use the hierarchical clustering with this data. Is this the correct way? Thanks in advance.