# How can I use hierarchicalClustering?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I use this code:

```
int c_count =cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<L2<float>  >(data,cluster,kmeans_param);
```

I got this error:

```
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ElementType'
```

How can I solve it?

My features is 3d (x,y,theta) that I want to cluster these.
when the classification was done.How can I access to cluster id for each feature?

Comment: please specify more about the code. the error seems very specific. are you sure you don't have identifier named 'ElementType'?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17460431/1601291) might be useful.

Comment: @ Aurelius :Use this template function is deprecated.